# Query error with Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql-server

When executing the following SQL query on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 :

```
SELECT 
   [ACCOUNT]
  ,[Mailto]
  ,[Site_addr_1]
  ,[Site_addr_2]
  ,[Site_addr_3]
  ,[State_Class]
  ,[Map_Facet]
  ,[Key_Map]
  ,[Neighborhood_Code]
  ,[Neighborhood_Group]
  ,[Econ_Area]
  ,[Yr_Impr]
  ,[Acreage]
  ,[Prior_Total_Market_Value]
  ,[Land_Value]
  ,[Improvement_Value]
  ,[Extra_features_Value]
  ,[Total_Appraised_Value]
  ,[Total_Building_Area]
  ,[Econ_Bld_Class]
  ,[LAND_USE_CODE]
FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Real_acct] 
LEFT JOIN [Pdata].[dbo].[Land] 
ON (Real_acct.ACCOUNT = LAND.ACCOUNT)
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'ACCOUNT'.
```

Comment: Which table's ACCOUNT value do you want to show up in the query--`Real_acct` or `LAND`?

Comment: The first column in the select.  SQL doesn't know which table to pull it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first column... the server doesn't know if you want `Real_acct.ACCOUNT` or `LAND.ACCOUNT`

Answer (score 4):

You are doing a join and it seems that both tables have the column `ACCOUNT` and sql server doesn't know if you want the column `ACCOUNT` from `Real_acct` or `Land`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   Real_acct.ACCOUNT -- or Land.ACCOUNT
  ,Mailto
  ,Site_addr_1
  ,Site_addr_2
  ,Site_addr_3
  ,State_Class
  ,Map_Facet
  ,Key_Map
  ,Neighborhood_Code
  ,Neighborhood_Group
  ,Econ_Area
  ,Yr_Impr
  ,Acreage
  ,Prior_Total_Market_Value
  ,Land_Value
  ,Improvement_Value
  ,Extra_features_Value
  ,Total_Appraised_Value
  ,Total_Building_Area
  ,Econ_Bld_Class
  ,LAND_USE_CODE
FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Real_acct] 
LEFT JOIN [Pdata].[dbo].[Land] 
ON (Real_acct.ACCOUNT = LAND.ACCOUNT)
```

Answer (score 0):

@majidarif is completely correct.
The reason is that both tables have a column named "Account".
You need to specify which table you want the value returned from.
Even if they are the same you need to be specific.